# Why does the page posts take so long?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, post, back, appcmd

I am having some problems with some page post backs that take a loooong time to execute. 
If I do a "appcmd list requests" I can get something like this:

```
REQUEST "79000001800004e3" (url:POST /dir/file.aspx, time:87219 msec, client:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, stage:ExecuteRequestHandler, module:ManagedPipelineHandler)
REQUEST "8600000080002f82" (url:POST /dir/file.aspx, time:61391 msec, client:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, stage:AcquireRequestState, module:Session)
REQUEST "5e00010280000420" (url:POST /dir/file.aspx, time:21047 msec, client:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, stage:AcquireRequestState, module:Session)
```

It's one particular file that causes the problem (dir/file.aspx in this case). It comes from the same IP-adress.  And the first on is from ManagedPipelineHandler module and the two after that from Session module.

I do not have any details about the web browser, or anything more about the client for that matter.

I have looked for sql dead locks and did not find any. There are no long running sql queries at all.

Do you have any idea of what can be the problem?

Regards.

Comment: ..and what does file.aspx do?

Comment: And what is the _size_ of the request? Perhaps they are posting a _huge_ file, for instance?

Comment: The file is a quite complicated form (too big to post here), but I do not believe huge files are posted. 

I have read that UpdatePanels can cause slow requests on IE. But these request length are crazy. Don't you think...?

I was more hoping there were some general ideas about problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks like the problem was due to the fact that Rapid Fail Protection was enabled on the server. When too many exceptions were thrown the application restarted, which takes quite a time to do, and during that time the requests were put on queue.